# Как реализовать анимацию открытия бокового меню (библиотека jfeinstein10) в приложении Android

Tags: java, android

Имеется приложение для Android, в котором реализовано выдвигающееся боковое меню с помощью [сторонней библиотеки SlidingMenu от jfeinstein10](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Реализовано все стандартно, также, как описано в README на GitHub (java):

(Мой кусок кода `OnCreate`)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    isShowContentOpen = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
    {
    mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    }
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null)
    {
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    }
    else
    {
        View v = new View(this);
        menu.setMenu(v);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
    if (mContent == null)
        mContent = new TitleListFragment();
    setFragment(mContent);
    setMenuFragment(new MenuFragment());
    initSlidingMenu();
}
```

Но теперь мне необходимо встроить анимацию открытия этого бокового меню.
Рассмотрев библиотеку, я понял, что это вполне возможно.
[Там присутствуют анимации Scale, Zoom, Slide (это в example)](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/anim)

Так вот, хотелось бы сделать анимацию Zoom для своей программы, но не пойму как...

То ли делать отдельный java (как в примере), а в `OnCreate` прописывать его (если да, то как именно прописывать), то ли сразу в `OnCreate` писать...

Comment: Navigation Drawer совсем не подходит?

Comment: Да не совсем хочется переделывать, тем более думаю, что не хватит знаний на это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать метод `setBehindCanvasTransformer` и передать ему в качестве аргумента анонимный класс

```
new CanvasTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformCanvas(Canvas canvas, float percentOpen) {
                float scale = (float) (percentOpen*0.25 + 0.75);
                canvas.scale(scale, scale, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);
            }
        }
```

в итоге должно получиться

```
menu.setBehindCanvasTransformer(new CanvasTransformer() {
                @Override
                public void transformCanvas(Canvas canvas, float percentOpen) {
                    float scale = (float) (percentOpen*0.25 + 0.75);
                    canvas.scale(scale, scale, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);
                }
            });
```

это добавить в `onCreate` Активити под строкой кода

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
```

Comment: Но почему выдаёт ошибки Unknown entity "Canvas Transformer", а также ошибку о невозможности перезаписи Override

Comment: А, точно, вот я дурак, все решила строчка private CanvasTransformer mTransformer;

Comment: Все работает, огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Не за что! Рад, что разобрались ;)